# Design interface to invoke external Service call from one Service

Tags: java, oop, generics, interface

I have 2 services A and B

Service A needs to make a HTTP call to Service B and get a response

I'm confused about designing an interface in Service A that would invoke Service B APIs

**APPROACH 1**

**DeliveryClient.java**

```
public interface DeliveryClient {
    PostNotificationResponse sendNotifcation(PostNotificationRequest request);
 }
```

**DeliveryClientImpl.java**

```
class DeliveryClientImpl implements  DeliveryClient{

   private static String baseEndPoint = "http://example";

   public DeliveryClientImpl() {

   }

   public PostNotificationResponse sendNotifcation(PostNotificationRequest request) {

     String postNotificationEndpoint = new StringBuilder(baseEndpoint).append("/send")
      // make the HTTP call

     return response
   }

}
```

**DRAWBACKS OF APPROACH 1**

- The interface request and response are tied to PostNotificationRequest and PostNotificationResponse
- In future if Service A talks to Service C instead of B would be hard to make changes with this approach

**APPROACH 2**

Design generic request and response classes

```
abstract class BaseRequest {

}

abstract class BaseResponse {

 }

 class NotificationRequest extends BaseRequest {

}
 class NotificationResponse extends BaseResponse {

}
```

**DeliveryClient.java**

```
public interface DeliveryClient {
    <R extends BaseResponse> R sendNotification(BaseRequest<T> request);
 }
```

**DeliveryClientImpl.java**

```
class DeliveryClientImpl implements DeliveryClient{

   private static String baseEndPoint = "http://example";

   public DeliveryClientImpl() {

   }

   public PostNotificationResponse sendNotifcation(PostNotificationRequest request) {

     String postNotificationEndpoint = new StringBuilder(baseEndpoint).append("/send")
      // make the HTTP call

     return response
   }

}
```

Comment: Approach C: Use OpenFeign, which lets you write the first interface and be finished with your work.

Comment: Unless you are developing infrastructure libraries, base the design of your service interfaces on the business concepts.